# Getting TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class '...Categorical'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run a Resnet model through Skorch for classification which I found in a research paper. I am still learning the ways of Torch and Skorch, and I'm unable to find what to fix to get this to work.

ResNet class:

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        d_numerical: int,
        categories: ty.Optional[ty.List[int]],
        d_embedding: int,
        d: int,
        d_hidden_factor: float,
        n_layers: int,
        activation: str,
        normalization: str,
        hidden_dropout: float,
        residual_dropout: float,
        d_out: int,
        regression: bool,
        categorical_indicator
) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    #categories = None #TODO
    def make_normalization():
        return {'batchnorm': nn.BatchNorm1d, 'layernorm': nn.LayerNorm}[
            normalization[0]
        ](d)
    self.categorical_indicator = categorical_indicator #Added
    self.regression = regression
    self.main_activation = deep.get_activation_fn(activation)
    self.last_activation = deep.get_nonglu_activation_fn(activation)
    self.residual_dropout = residual_dropout
    self.hidden_dropout = hidden_dropout

    d_in = d_numerical
    d_hidden = int(d * d_hidden_factor)

    if categories is not None:
        d_in += len(categories) * d_embedding
        category_offsets = torch.tensor([0] + categories[:-1]).cumsum(0)
        self.register_buffer('category_offsets', category_offsets)
        self.category_embeddings = nn.Embedding(int(sum(categories)), d_embedding)
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.category_embeddings.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
        print(f'{self.category_embeddings.weight.shape}')

    self.first_layer = nn.Linear(d_in, d) # 1, 256
    self.layers = nn.ModuleList(
        [
            nn.ModuleDict(
                {
                    'norm': make_normalization(),
                    'linear0': nn.Linear(
                        d, d_hidden * (2 if activation.endswith('glu') else 1)
                    ),
                    'linear1': nn.Linear(d_hidden, d),
                }
            )
            for _ in range(n_layers)
        ]
    )
    self.last_normalization = make_normalization()
    self.head = nn.Linear(d, d_out) # 256, 1

def forward(self, x) -> Tensor:
    if not self.categorical_indicator is None:
        x_num = x[:, ~self.categorical_indicator].float()
        x_cat = x[:, self.categorical_indicator].long() #TODO
    else:
        x_num = x
        x_cat = None
    x = []
    if x_num is not None:
        x.append(x_num)
    if x_cat is not None:
        x.append(
            self.category_embeddings(x_cat + self.category_offsets[None]).view(
                x_cat.size(0), -1
            )
        )
    x = torch.cat(x, dim=-1)

    x = self.first_layer(x)
    for layer in self.layers:
        layer = ty.cast(ty.Dict[str, nn.Module], layer)
        z = x
        z = layer['norm'](z)
        z = layer['linear0'](z)
        z = self.main_activation(z)
        if self.hidden_dropout:
            z = F.dropout(z, self.hidden_dropout, self.training)
        z = layer['linear1'](z)
        if self.residual_dropout:
            z = F.dropout(z, self.residual_dropout, self.training)
        x = x + z
    x = self.last_normalization(x)
    x = self.last_activation(x)
    x = self.head(x)
    if not self.regression:
        x = x.squeeze(-1)
    return x

class InputShapeSetterResnet(skorch.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, regression=False, batch_size=None,
                 categorical_indicator=None):
        self.categorical_indicator = categorical_indicator
        self.regression = regression
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def on_train_begin(self, net, X, y):
        print("categorical_indicator", self.categorical_indicator)
        if self.categorical_indicator is None:
            d_numerical = X.shape[1]
            categories = None
        else:
            d_numerical = X.shape[1] - sum(self.categorical_indicator)
            # categories = list((X[:, self.categorical_indicator].max(0) + 1).astype(int))
            categories = [sum(self.categorical_indicator)]
        net.set_params(module__d_numerical=d_numerical,
        module__categories=categories, #FIXME #lib.get_categories(X_cat),
        module__d_out=2 if self.regression == False else 1) #FIXME#D.info['n_classes'] if D.is_multiclass else 1,
        print("Numerical features: {}".format(d_numerical))
        print("Categories {}".format(categories))
```

Skorch Wrapper:

```
def create_resnet_skorch(id, wandb_run=None, use_checkpoints=True,
                     categorical_indicator=None, **kwargs):
print(kwargs)
if "verbose" not in kwargs:
    verbose = 0
else:
    verbose = kwargs.pop("verbose")
if "lr_scheduler" not in kwargs:
    lr_scheduler = False
else:
    lr_scheduler = kwargs.pop("lr_scheduler")
if "es_patience" not in kwargs.keys():
    es_patience = 40
else:
    es_patience = kwargs.pop('es_patience')
if "lr_patience" not in kwargs.keys():
    lr_patience = 30
else:
    lr_patience = kwargs.pop('lr_patience')
optimizer = kwargs.pop('optimizer')
if optimizer == "adam":
    optimizer = Adam
elif optimizer == "adamw":
    optimizer = AdamW
elif optimizer == "sgd":
    optimizer = SGD
device = kwargs.pop('device')
if device == "cuda": # ! only for CPU training, is cuda by default
    device = "cpu"
batch_size = kwargs.pop('batch_size')
callbacks = [InputShapeSetterResnet(categorical_indicator=categorical_indicator),
             EarlyStopping(monitor="valid_loss",
                           patience=es_patience)] 
callbacks.append(EpochScoring(scoring='accuracy', name='train_accuracy', on_train=True))

if lr_scheduler:
    callbacks.append(LRScheduler(policy=ReduceLROnPlateau, patience=lr_patience, min_lr=2e-5,
                                 factor=0.2))  # FIXME make customizable
if use_checkpoints:
    callbacks.append(Checkpoint(dirname="skorch_cp", f_params=r"params_{}.pt".format(id), f_optimizer=None,
                                f_criterion=None))
if not wandb_run is None:
    callbacks.append(WandbLogger(wandb_run, save_model=False))
    callbacks.append(LearningRateLogger())

if not categorical_indicator is None:
    categorical_indicator = torch.BoolTensor(categorical_indicator)

mlp_skorch = NeuralNetClassifier(
    ResNet,
    # Shuffle training data on each epoch
    criterion=torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    batch_size=max(batch_size, 1),  # if batch size is float, it will be reset during fit
    iterator_train__shuffle=True,
    module__d_numerical=1,  # will be change when fitted
    module__categories=None,  # will be change when fitted
    module__d_out=1,  # idem
    module__regression=False,
    module__categorical_indicator=categorical_indicator,
    verbose=verbose,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    **kwargs
)

return mlp_skorch
```

Skorch Model:

```
<class 'skorch.classifier.NeuralNetClassifier'>[uninitialized](
 module=<class 'tabular.bin.resnet.ResNet'>,
  module__activation=reglu,
  module__categorical_indicator=tensor([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False]),
  module__categories=None,
  module__d=256,
  module__d_embedding=128,
  module__d_hidden_factor=2,
  module__d_numerical=1,
  module__d_out=1,
  module__hidden_dropout=0.2,
  module__n_layers=8,
  module__normalization=['batchnorm'],
  module__regression=False,
  module__residual_dropout=0.2,
)
```

I have 8 columns in X for training, 1 of which is a categorical column which is to be embedding through an embedding layer in the NN. From what I've found so far, that is the root of this error since it's coming across this categorical class in execution. But in the forward method, it's supposed to have an embedding layer for the same. Any idea what changes I might need to make for the same?

Error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 639, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skorch/classifier.py", line 142, in fit
    return super(NeuralNetClassifier, self).fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skorch/net.py", line 917, in fit
    self.partial_fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skorch/net.py", line 876, in partial_fit
    self.fit_loop(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skorch/net.py", line 789, in fit_loop
    self.run_single_epoch(dataset_train, training=True, prefix="train",
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skorch/net.py", line 822, in run_single_epoch
    for data in self.get_iterator(dataset, training=training):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 74, in default_collate
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 74, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 86, in default_collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical'>
```

Comment: The problem has absolutely nothing to do with the model. It's about the dataset class which you did not provide here.

Comment: Okay, can you expand on the dataset class please? I am not able to access it within the skorch model as well.

Comment: I read the stacktrace again and saw `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`. So maybe you just need to change `y_train` from whatever it is now into either integer of the class index or one-hot encoded tensor. I've no idea what skorch needs but you could try both.

Comment: Like, `pandas.get_dummies(y_train)` would probably give you one-hot and adding `.argmax(1)` will turn that into indices. Just "probably" because I don't know what the data looks like now.

Comment: Honestly I think it's a whole lot easier to just use Pytorch normally instead of any wrappers. [This](https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/blob/master/main.py) is an example of that and I really think it is less than 639 lines.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I converted the dtypes of both X and y, after which I'm not getting any error. But now it's giving me this error in the forward()

`self.category_embeddings(x_cat + self.category_offsets[None]).view(
(Pdb) n
IndexError: index out of range in self`

Comment: That's the problem with what exactly do you want to do with the model. Why do you need `nn.Embedding` in the first place is probably a good place to start. Especially if what you want to do is classification.

Comment: Other than that you need to check input dimension of the tensor in `forward`, by print it or in some IDE debug it.

Comment: nn.Embedding is for the categorical columns that's in the input. The input dimension should be equal to 1 or 8? (no. of input tabular columns)